# Input elements overlapping navigation (search button and checkbox)

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I'm currently running into this problem, that some elements like checkbox (label) and searchbutton (input) are always stacked above my navigation.

I tried a lot like setting opacity, positions, z-index (including a position which is not static), removed border backgrounds... but no success.

```
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9998;
```

Answer (score 0):

please check with position: relative; css

Comment: wich element ? I already tried a lot with positions and z-indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.search input {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: then the complete searchbox is permanently over the navigation dropdown. Id like that the dropdown is always over every other element.

Answer (score 0):

For those wich running on the same problem like me. It's because my nav-container was set to `position: static` !!
I changed it to `position: relative` now it's working fine !!

Comment: It wasn't set to position static, every element's position is static by default.